# Many moons in same orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, moons, n-body-problem

Is it possible to have a stable orbit comprised of many moons(>2) that keep themselves roughly equal distance apart?

Sort of like Epimetheus and Janus around Saturn but comprised of many moons.

The idea being that an image sort of like this would be able to be seen.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have small moons in the two stable (L4 and L5) [Lagrangian points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) of a main moon, like the Saturn moon [Dione's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dione_%28moon%29) companions Helene and Polydeuces, or [Tethys'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethys_%28moon%29) Telesto and Calypso.

If you want more than three moons, you can organize them in a [Klemperer rosette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemperer_rosette), although this type of configuration is not stable.

Another option is to have a huge number of small fragments orbiting inside the
[Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit), preventing them from forming a larger object. In a way, the rings of Saturn can be thought of like many small moons orbiting in the same orbit.

[image: rings of Saturn]

Comment: Tethys also has Calypso as a Trojan, same reference as given.  Edited in.